Write a function to insert an element x after position k in a 1-dimensional array a with n parts death
Write a function to insert an element x after position k in a 1-dimensional array a with n parts
death.use code c.
I really hope you can get help from me when helping me solve this problem, this problem is actually quite difficult for me. Thank you for taking some of your time to help me solve this problem.

Is this an interview question?
